# Php/Javascript cross connection issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So i have a contact page that runs some php and in that php if the email sends through correctly it runs a javascript command. I have two javascript commands one to change page and one to alert the person sending the email. Here is the code:

```
    if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.location.assign("http://dtc.bz/twitch/index.html");
        $('.alertfeed').show();
    </script>
    <?php
    }else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

When I run it. It redirects me to the correct page but the second command within the php page. So how do I get the second line of the javascript run on the page I want it to redirect to?

Answer (score 1):

After the page redirection no code will be executed, that's the reason "$('.alertfeed').show();" is not getting triggered. To do this you have to redirect the page first and on the page you have redirected then execute the next command.

Something like

```
window.location.assign("http://dtc.bz/twitch/index.html?redirected=yes");
```

now on the index.html check if redirected param and execute this command in php

```
<?php if($_GET['redirected']=='yes')
{
   echo "<script>$('.alertfeed').show();</script>";
}?>
```

Update: Using Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = window.location.pathname;

   var pieces = url.split("?");
   if(pieces[1]=='redirected=yes'){
     $('.alertfeed').show();
   }
});
```

Working Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/sLEgJ/4/

Comment: it shows this $('.alertfeed').show(); but doesn't run the command

Comment: Try to just echo "<script>alert('hello world')</script>"; if it's working then check if index.html has included jquery plugin.

Comment: no the script just shows up on the page you can check it out it should be in the middle of the page http://dtc.bz/twitch

Comment: problem is you are putting php script in html page which is not parsing php code simply printing it. you can change it to javascript. Let me send you in a second.

Comment: you can place it in head after jquery file included. You can wrap the code in document.ready, i have updated the code above.

Comment: Where would I put the code you can view source of my site i put it in body look on lines 92-106

Comment: yes i saw it.. there is a message showing up too "Success! You feedback was successfully sent! " what else you are expecting?

Comment: man you have kept the url static var url = 'http://dtc.bz/twitch/index.html?redirected=yes';
it should be 
var url = window.location.pathname;

Comment: update this line of code if(pieces[1]=='redirected=yes') instead checking as array. Updated above code!

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting redirected because there is no condition given for redirecting.

Thats why its redirecting you every time you run it.

Comment: I have a condition. Updating post

Comment: Once you redirect the user you wont be able to run script from previous page. So try: after redirecting to the page, on load run jQuery fadeIn() to show the element http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/